# Servlets: print statement present in a method called by servlet are not printing

Tags: java, servlets, logging, printing

I have a servlet which calls another method which is in another class called - Util.
I have sys print lines in Util but they do not print on logs only the print statement in servlet are printed in logs. Is this expected?

Comment: @shekharsuman ...thanks for your reply, yes its helpful but I still have to try it out in my code ..will accept your answer after that, tx again!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is as expected because you can't use console-based statements like `System.out.println()` to print logs. You will have to use **`PrintWriter objects`** to print logs.

Comment: i tried PrintWriter with system.out stream , it diidnt worked for me                  PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
                    pw.println(m1);
                    pw.println("In Util");

Comment: You are incorrect in trying that, you need to use `PrintWriter writerA = response.getWriter();` @Green where response is a type of HttpServletResponse.

Comment: Hi , i tried I am still not getting it to work. I have a servlet S and a util class U so i create obj of U in S and I need to print the details from U. Are so suggesting to pass the resp obj to U method and print , is there no other way.

Comment: do u have target to reach some reputation points ? ..... i dont agree with your answer it didnt helped me....in my scenario of code your answer is not the solution......i m not accepting !!

Comment: @Green-I found that you're hurt by any comment of mine. I am extremely sorry if I posted something so wrong. But,just a question whether you're able to get it work OR you're still facing problems? Please reply OR post a better answer if that worked for you.